# Weird Apache Error Log

Tags: security, debian, debian-squeeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these weird access requests?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384836/what-are-these-weird-access-requests)

```
[Thu May 03 11:39:36 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /var/www/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)
[Thu May 03 11:39:36 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /var/www/phpMyAdmin
[Thu May 03 11:39:37 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/scripts
[Thu May 03 11:39:37 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /var/www/pma
[Thu May 03 11:39:37 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /var/www/myadmin
[Thu May 03 11:39:38 2012] [error] [client 200.159.40.31] File does not exist: /var/www/MyAdmin
```

Is someone attacking my server and if so what can I do to prevent this? I am on a Debian Squeeze.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are breaking attempts. It is normal to receive such requests on an online web server. No need to worry about it as it returns 404 error (not found).

You need just to make sure you don't have a private data exposed on this server.